# How to make up in pixels for android using Cordova Phonegap

Tags: cordova, pixel

I have knew that you can download Cordova and work with android app like with html page. Can I use pixel make up when work with it and use someone like zoomout function if screen size smaller than my PSD width / height parameters. Or I haven't another way than % make up

Answer (score 0):

You can work with phonegap as you are working with regular sites. Due to fragmentation on screen size of Android device, maybe you need to make good use of percentage based css layout and media queries in your css.